# Need help Tab buttons in xslt

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, xslt-1.0

I'm a script programmer for a call center. I create webpages for agents to use when speaking with customers. I've been working on this  project for about a week n a half but now i'm at a hold up point. I cant figure out how to create tabs that will produce only the information from the section of the tab selected. I'll try to get as detailed as possible! 
 here's my Xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <link href="/USA800/Stylesheets/usa800.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/usa800/ClientSideScripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"/>
    <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[/* Plugin:  highlight v4 Descr:  Highlights arbitrary terms.  
Source:  <http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html> License: MIT license.  Author:  Johann Burkard Website: <http://johannburkard.de> Email:   <mailto:jb@eaio.com> */

`jQuery.fn.highlight = function(pat) {
 function innerHighlight(node, pat) {


var skip = 0;
if (node.nodeType == 3) {
var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
if (pos >= 0) {
var spannode = document.createElement('span');
spannode.className = 'highlight';
var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
skip = 1;
}
}
else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes &&      
!/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
}
}
return skip;
}
return this.length && pat && pat.length ? this.each(function() {
innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase());
}) : this;
};

jQuery.fn.removeHighlight = function() {
return this.find("span.highlight").each(function() {
this.parentNode.firstChild.nodeName;
 with (this.parentNode) {
replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
normalize();
}
}).end();
};



$(document).ready(function(){
var globalTable = $("#KBase").html();

$("#search").keyup(function() {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase();       

    if(value.length > 3) {          
        $("#KBase").removeHighlight();
        $("#KBase").highlight(value);
        $("#KBase").find("tr").each(function(index) {
            if (index === 0) return;
            var id = $(this).find("td").text().toLowerCase();                   
            $(this).toggle(id.indexOf(value) !== -1);
        });
    }
    else if (value.length == 0) {
        $("#KBase").html(globalTable);
    }   
});
 });

]]>
    </script>

    <style>.highlight
{
background-color:blue;
}</style>


    <center>
        <img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m5krqjdKum1r0z3y7o1_500.gif" alt="Learn you must!" style="width:208px;height:145px"/>
        <br/>

        <script>function scrollWin(x, y) {
                window.scrollTo(x, y); }</script>

        <h3>
            <b>Click Tab to Search Location</b>
        </h3>

        <button onclick="scrollWin(0,11535)">
            <i>
                <b>ATV</b>
            </i>
        </button>

        <button onclick="scrollWin(0,420)">
            <i>
                <b>About Polaris</b>
            </i>
        </button>
        <button onclick="scrollWin(0,79999)">
            <i>
                <b>Slingshot</b>
            </i>
        </button>

        <button onclick="scrollWin(0,83550)">
            <i>
                <b>Snowmobile</b>
            </i>
        </button>
        <br/>
        <button onclick="scrollWin(0,90092)">
            <i>
                <b>Victory</b>
            </i>
        </button>
        <button onclick="scrollWin(0,49550)">
            <i>
                <b>Indian Motorcycle</b>
            </i>
        </button>
        <button onclick="scrollWin(0,64890)">
            <i>
                <b>Mailing List</b>
            </i>
        </button>
        <button onclick="scrollWin(0,75800)">
            <i>
                <b>RZR</b>
            </i>
        </button>
        <br/>
        <button onclick="scrollWin(0,37112)">
            <i>
                <b>BRUTUS</b>
            </i>
        </button>
        <button onclick="scrollWin(0,74700)">
            <i>
                <b>Ranger</b>
            </i>
        </button>

        <button onclick="scrollWin(0,65409)">
            <i>
                <b>Military</b>
            </i>
        </button>
        <button onclick="scrollWin(0,39990)">
            <i>
                <b>Electric Vehicles</b>
            </i>
        </button>
        <br/>
        <button onclick="scrollWin(0,69465)">
            <i>
                <b>Polaris ESC</b>
            </i>
        </button>
        <button onclick="scrollWin(0,38125)">
            <i>
                <b>Documents</b>
            </i>
        </button>
    </center>




    <b>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">Keyword's Search  </xsl:text>
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search..."/>
    </b>
    <br/>
    <br/>


    <table id="KBase" width="100%" border="11.5" frame="border" style="color:#CC3300" bgcolor="#B6FFE7">
        <tr bgcolor="#E8F7FF" style="color:#606060">
            <th>
                <b>Case Type 1</b>
            </th>
            <th>
                <b>Case Type 2</b>
            </th>
            <th>
                <b>Title</b>
            </th>
            <th>
                <b>Body</b>
            </th>
            <th>
                <b>Script</b>
            </th>
            <th>
                <b>Created</b>
            </th>
            <th>
                <b>Last Modified</b>
            </th>
        </tr>


        <xsl:apply-templates select="document/article">
            <xsl:sort select="casetype1" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:sort order="descending" select="title"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>

    <button onclick="scrollWin(0,0)">
        <i>
            <b>Back To Top</b>
        </i>
    </button>
</xsl:template>
```

Ok now here's a smaller version of my XML:

```
<document>
<article id="1">
    <title>International Inquiries</title>
    <body>Thank you for contacting Polaris Industries!</body>
    <script>May i please have your phone number area code first.</script>
    <casetype1>ATV</casetype1>
    <casetype2>Dealer</casetype2>
    <created sort="201206011355">06/01/2012 13:55</created>
    <modified sort="201411191848">11/19/2014 18:48</modified>
</article>
<article id="2">
    <title>National Accounts – Fleet Sales</title>
    <body>Polaris has a National Accounts/Fleet Sales group that sells Polaris vehicles direct to businesses.</body>
    <script></script>
    <casetype1>ATV</casetype1>
    <casetype2>Product</casetype2>
    <created sort="201402171253">02/17/2014 12:53</created>
    <modified sort="201411191838">11/19/2014 18:38</modified>
</article>
<article id="3">
    <title>Motorcycle Consumer Session Focus Group</title>
    <body>We have been recruiting for 10-15 Victory and Indian customers in 3 markets to take place in a 2.5 hour meeting (with a 30 min check in time) regarding their customer experience with Victory and Indian.</body>
    <script></script>
    <casetype1>Indian Motorcycle</casetype1>
    <casetype2>Marketing</casetype2>
    <created sort="201411111021">11/11/2014 10:21</created>
    <modified sort="201411181845">11/18/2014 18:45</modified>
</article>
<article id="4">
    <title>2015 SNOWCHECK Select Golden Ticket</title>
    <body>Golden Ticket (RMK models only)</body>
    <script></script>
    <casetype1>Snowmobile</casetype1>
    <casetype2>Marketing</casetype2>
    <created sort="201403211233">03/21/2014 12:33</created>
    <modified sort="201411181521">11/18/2014 15:21</modified>
</article></document>
```

Ok, i sorted the table by "casetype1" ascending and "title" by descending. Then I added color, a GIF, and a keyword search. Now the issue i have is with the tabs at the top of the page. Here's what i want to happen, when the agent click the tab i want ONLY the section i selected to be shown so the agents are able to cipher through the information page quicker and more efficient. Can this be done? If so how?

Comment: Can someone please help?

Comment: The problem is: You've tagged this question with `xslt` and `xml` - so, answerers from those topics will look at your question. But this is unrelated to XSLT, this might be an HTML, CSS, JQuery or JS problem. Retagging the question might help.